# How to check, whether exception was raisen in the current scope?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, debugging, exception

I use the following code to call an arbitrary callable `f()` with appropriate number of parameters:

```
try:
    res = f(arg1)
except TypeError:
    res = f(arg1, arg2)
```

If `f()` is a two parameter function, calling it with just one parameter raises `TypeError`, so the function can be called properly in the `except` branch.

The problem is when `f()` is one-parameter function and the exception is raisen in the body of `f()` (possibly because of a bad call to some function), for example:

```
def f(arg):
    map(arg) # raises TypeError
```

The control flow goes to the `except` branch because of the internal error of `f()`. Of course calling `f()` with two arguments raises a new `TypeError`. Then instead of traceback to the original error I get traceback to the call of `f()` with two parameters, which is much less helpful when debugging.

How can my code recognize exceptions raised not in the current scope to reraise them?

I want to write the code like this:

```
try:
    res = f(arg1)
except TypeError:
    if exceptionRaisedNotInTheTryBlockScope(): # <-- subject of the question
        raise
    res = f(arg1, arg2)
```

I know I can use a walkarround by adding `exc_info = sys.exc_info()` in the `except` block.

One of assumptions is I have no control over `f()` since it is given by user of my module. Also its `__name__` attribute may be other than `'f'`. Internal exception may be raised by bad recurrent call to `f()`.
The walkarround is unsuitable since it complicates debugging by the author of `f()`.

Comment: To re-raise you simply do `raise` ad the end of your `except` block. Traceback unwraps call stack from the point where the error occured and shows exactly where and how many levels down it happened.  To see traceback either don't catch the exceptin or use a traceback function like print_exc()

Comment: @Muposat reraising is not what I am asking about. I need to reraise conditionally, depending  on whether the exception was raised in the current scope or deeper.

Comment: You can save it for later `except TypeError as e: saved_e = e` and later on you can check: `if saved_e: raise saved_e`

Comment: It sounds like you are doing something in an odd way. Typically when I catch an exception I do the desired processing in the `except` block and simply allow it to propagate by ending the block with `raise` (no arguments)

Comment: @Muposat I am doing it on a purpose: *to call an arbitrary callable `f()` with an appropriate number of parameters*. It is "better to seek forgiveness than permission" pythonic pattern.

Comment: @Muposat I have edited the question

Comment: see if you can use getargspec(), as shown in my answer

Comment: @Muposat thought about it. It does not work for callable objects in Python 2.7

Comment: Sorry, I do not know Python 2. I showed you multiple ways to accomplish the task, you will need to see what you can apply to Python 2. Remember that Python's "to seek forgiveness" paradigm means to keep it simple -- just retry with 2 arguments and let it fail. If it fails again then the trace from both errors will be present for debugging.

Comment: As far as `traceback....confusing for the user` -- why does the user see traceback in the first place? Save it to log file and email it to yourself, then tell the user "i am working on it". Except when it is a user error, in which case I tell him exactly what his error is and don't bother sending myself an email :)

Comment: @Muposat: Because the user is a programmer using my module - and possibly author of `f()`. Then if there is a bug in `f()`, it is (s)he who is debugging it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out:

```
def exceptionRaisedNotInTheTryBlockScope():
    return sys.exc_info()[2].tb_next is not None
```

`sys.exc_info()` returns a 3-element `tuple`. Its last element is the traceback of the last exception. If the traceback object is the only one in the traceback chain, then the exception has been raisen in the scope of the `try` block (https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html).

According to https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info, it should be avoided to store the traceback value.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the exception object and examine it.

```
try:
    res = f(arg1)
except TypeError as e:
    if "f() missing 1 required positional argument" in e.args[0]: 
        res = f(arg1, arg2)
    else:
        raise
```

Frankly, though, not going the extra length to classify the exception should work fine as you should be getting both the original traceback and the secondary traceback if the error originated inside f() -- debugging should not be a problem.

Also, if you have control over f() you can make second argument optional and not have to second-guess it:

```
def f(a, b=None):
    pass
```

Now you can call it either way.

How about this:

```
import inspect

if len(inspect.getargspec(f).args) == 1:
    res = f(arg1)
else:
    res = f(arg1, arg2)
```

Comment: Thanks, but there are two problems: I can not assume any control over `f()` since it may be given by user of my module. The second problem is that `f.__name__` (used in the error message) in most cases would be different than `'f'`. Moreover, the internal bad call may be a recurrent call to `f()` rendering message analysis useless... The trick with traceback capture works fine for me, but it will be confusing for the user.